# How can I get this header navbar into a hamburger menu for mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css

how can I get this header navbar into a hamburger menu for mobile ? I tried many things I saw on internet but didn't work..

I guess I need to use media queries with it but I'm not sure.
Thanks for your help

Here's the code:

```css
header {
    z-index: 9;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #583760;
}

header::after {
    content:  '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.logo {
    max-height: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

nav {
    margin-right: 80px;
    float: right;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
    padding-top: 42px;
}

nav a {
    color: #e5e5e5;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #CFCFCF;
}
```

```html
<header>
      <img src="images/GameStar-Blanc.png" alt="logo" class="logo">

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">A LA UNE </a></li>
          <li><a href="#actualite">L'ACTUALITE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#guides">GUIDES ET ASTUCES</a></li>
          <li><a href="#prochainement">PROCHAINEMENT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
  </header>
```

............

Answer (score 0):

```
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  float: initial;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .23s;
}

nav.active {
  width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Thansk for your answer. Just tested and it adds a red window to the right of my page with my links but isn't transforming into Hamburger menu

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("#open-menu");
const menu = document.querySelector("nav");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    menu.classList.toggle("active");
})
```

```css
header {
    z-index: 9;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #583760;
}

.logo {
    max-height: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

nav {
    margin-right: 80px;
    float: right;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
    padding-top: 42px;
}

nav a {
    color: #e5e5e5;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #CFCFCF;
}

button {
    float: right;
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
    button {
        display: block;
    }

    nav {
        position: absolute;
        margin-right: 0;
        top: 100%;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: red;
        display: none;
    }
    
    nav.active {
        display: block;
    }

    nav li {
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
    <header>
        <img src="images/GameStar-Blanc.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
  
        <button id="open-menu">Toggle Menu</button>

        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">A LA UNE </a></li>
            <li><a href="#actualite">L'ACTUALITE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#guides">GUIDES ET ASTUCES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#prochainement">PROCHAINEMENT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

    </header>
```

Suggestion: use flexbox to create navbar ?

Answer (score 0):

To do this with just CSS is pretty high-level. Here is a solution using pure CSS. It's important for you to know how this works, so please do your due diligence. I tried to make the CSS friendly by including notes and separating out each major style in different sections.

```css
/* CORE STYLES */
:root {
  --primary-color: #583760;
  --overlay-color: #583760;
  --ani-content-speed: 1s;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
}



/* MENU STYLES */
.togger-an {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.toggler {
  visibility: visible !important;
}

.togger-an .toggler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.togger-an .cta-mob {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* Line Animation */
.togger-an .cta-mob > div {
  position: relative;
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

/* Line Animation - Top & Bottom */
.togger-an .cta-mob > div::before,
.togger-an .cta-mob > div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: inherit;
}

/* Moves Line Down */
.togger-an .cta-mob > div::after {
  top: 10px;
}

/* Toggler Animation */
.togger-an .toggler:checked + .cta-mob > div {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

/* Turns Lines Into X */
.togger-an .toggler:checked + .cta-mob > div:before,
.togger-an .toggler:checked + .cta-mob > div:after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

/* Rotate On Hover When Checked */
.togger-an .toggler:checked:hover + .cta-mob > div {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}

/* Show Menu */
.togger-an .toggler:checked ~ .ani-content {
  visibility: visible;
}

.togger-an .toggler:checked ~ .ani-content > div {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-duration: var(--ani-content-speed);
}

.togger-an .toggler:checked ~ .ani-content > div > div {
  opacity: 1;
  transition:  opacity 0.4s ease 0.4s;
}

.togger-an .ani-content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.togger-an .ani-content > div {
  background: var(--overlay-color);
  width: 200vw;
  height: 300vw;
  display: flex;
  flex: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.togger-an .ani-content > div > div {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 90vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}

.togger-an .ani-content > div > div > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.togger-an .ani-content > div > div > ul > li > a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.4s ease;
}

/* Main Navbar No Media */
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #583760;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  align-items: center;
}
.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 40px;
}

.navbar li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color:rgba(13, 110, 139, 0.75)
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* nav media */
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .togger-an {
      display: block;
  }

  .navbar li a {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="images/GameStar-Blanc.png" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">A LA UNE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">L'ACTUALITE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">GUIDES ET ASTUCES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PROCHAINMENT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="togger-an">
    <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
    <div class="cta-mob"><div></div></div>
    <div class="ani-content">
      <div>
        <div>
            <div class="logo">
              <img src="images/GameStar-Blanc.png" alt="logo">
            </div>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">A LA UNE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">L'ACTUALITE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">GUIDES ET ASTUCES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PROCHAINMENT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```